# Thermodynamics - Entropy Change in an Isolated System and the State Postulate

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I was thinking about something. Consider a isolated system consisting of hot and cold water in a rigid tank. The process is to basically to let them reach an equilibrium temperature.
Now, because it's isolated, u2=u1.
And, because it's a rigid tank, v2=v1.
And, because it's internally irreversible (hot and cold water heat exchange is going to generate entropy), s2>s1.
The state postulate clearly states that for this kind of system, we only need 2 independent and intensive properties (v and u both satisfy this). So because v2=v1 and u2=u1, the states should be equal before and after the process. But s is a state variable and, because of that, s2 should be equal to s1. 
So, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial "state" is not really a state of thermodynamic equilibrium. As you yourself said, you have separated hot and cold water regions which subsequently mix together. Since your initial "state" is not a true thermodynamic equilibrium state it is not describable by just the two thermodynamic variables u (energy?) and v (volume). Obviously, you need additional (non-thermodynamic) variables to describe how the hot and cold water regions are situated in the tank.

Your final state, on the other hand, is a true thermodynamic equilibrium state. The hot and cold water regions have mixed together and all the water in the tank is at the same temperature T. (BTW, that's another clue that your initial "state" was not a true thermodynamic state: Since it consists of hot and cold water regions, it's not possible to ascribe a unique temperature, which is a thermodynamic variable, to the initial "state".)